# Ajax POST requests loosing payload in sencha app + phonegap

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm developing a sencha web application with sencha touch 2.1.x
This app needs to run on a web server and as well as an iOS app, packaged with phonegap 3.1.

The web server version works well, but I'm facing some problems in the iOS version, when executing Ajax POST requests. This is a sample code:

```
var jsonParams = 
{
    "username": loginParams.user,
    "password": loginParams.pwd,
    "serverVersion": serverVersion
};
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonParams);
console.log(jsonStr);

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: internalRoute.LOGIN,
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    method: 'POST',
    scope:this,
    params: jsonStr,
    success: function(response){
        .....
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        .....
    },
});
```

Sometimes this requests works fine from the iOS version packaged with phonegap, but randomly it fails, because the post payload is empty. The `console.log(jsonStr)` prints the correct data, but the server receives no data. I also used an HTTP sniffer to capture the sent package, and it contains no POST payload.

Changed the code to user jQuery `$.ajax`instead of `Ext.Ajax.request`, and the problem persists. 
Any idea of what can be wrong?

Thx

Comment: Are your jsonParams always the same? That would seem like the logical failure point to me.

Comment: jsonParams is filled with login data entered by the user. `console.log(jsonStr)` always show that jsonParams data is correct.

Comment: Since this is failing inside a hybrid app, is it possible you're sniffing the CORS pre-flight request? That wouldn't have the actual payload. The pre-flight would be immediately followed by the POST request as long as pre-flight didn't hit an error.

Comment: No, that's not the case. I'm sniffing the POST request that sometimes contains json data for login, but sometimes it contains nothing, with content-length = 0 although the console.log always prints correct data in jsonStr var.

Comment: Added implementation of `beforeSend` callback to check request data, and it's correct, but the server receives nothing. The server is accessed via a proxy. Could it be a proxy issue?

Comment: I guess it could be the proxy... I can't imagine it being anything else at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's actually a proxy issue, nothing to do with sencha or phonegap. 
If I deactivate the proxy, I don't get other external resources, but this issue never happens.
Will search how to fix the proxy issue.
Thanks